# Which tags are questions featured in?

Tags: support, tags, bounty

I'm thinking of starting a bounty on my question [Preserve JSON arrays while sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863071/preserve-json-arrays-while-sorting). Which tag will the question be featured in? All of them? Only some?

Currently the question is tagged in:

- JavaScript
- PHP
- Arrays
- JSON
- Sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will appear in the "featured" tab of all of the tags on the question.

(You can test this yourself by going to any question with a bounty, clicking on each of the tags on the question, and finding the question on the "featured" tab.)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of that... now I feel a bit silly. Thank you for confirming.